# DBI::ProxyServer: Problem with writing a log-file

Tags: perl, logging, proxy, dbi

When starting the proxyserver [(DBI::ProxyServer)](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI%3a%3aProxyServer) with

```
dbiproxy --logfile C:\WINDOWS\temp\dbiproxy.log --debug 1 --localport 2000
```

or with

```
dbiproxy --configfile dbiproxy.config
```

everything works, except the writing of a logfile.
My dbiproxy config file:

```
{ 'logfile'     => 'C:\WINDOWS\temp\dbiproxy.log',
  'localport'   => '2000',
  'debug'       => 1,   }
```

I pass a filename, but the [Net::Daemon::Log](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aDaemon%3a%3aLog) needs a filehandle.
Is the code not OK or have I missed something?

```
# Net/Daemon.pm
sub ReadConfigFile {
    my($self, $file, $options, $args) = @_;
    # ...   
    my $copts = do $file;
    # ...
    # Override current configuration with config file options.
    while (my($var, $val) = each %$copts) {
    $self->{$var} = $val;
    }
}
sub new ($$;$) {
    my($class, $attr, $args) = @_;
    my($self) = $attr ? \%$attr : {};
    bless($self, (ref($class) || $class));
    my $options = ($self->{'options'} ||= {});
    # ...
    # ...
    my $file = $options->{'configfile'}  ||  $self->{'configfile'};
    if ($file) {
    $self->ReadConfigFile($file, $options, $args);
    }
    while (my($var, $val) = each %$options) {
    $self->{$var} = $val;
    }
    # ...
    # ...
    $self;
}

# Net/Daemon/Log.pm
sub OpenLog($) {
    my $self = shift;
    return 1 unless ref($self);
    return $self->{'logfile'} if defined($self->{'logfile'});
    # ...
    # ...
}
sub Log ($$$;@) {
    my($self, $level, $format, @args) = @_;
    my $logfile = !ref($self) || $self->OpenLog();
    # ...
    # ...
    if ($logfile) {
    my $logtime = $self->LogTime();
    # <- get this far, but don't pass the "ref($logfile)"
    if (ref($logfile)) {
        $logfile->print(sprintf("$logtime $level, $tid$format\n", @args));
    } else {
        printf STDERR ("$logtime $level, $tid$format\n", @args);
    }
    } elsif (my $eventLog = $self->{'eventLog'}) {
    # ...
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about putting

```
'logfile' => IO::File->new('C:\WINDOWS\temp\dbiproxy.log', 'a'),
```

into your dbiproxy config file? I don't have a way how to test it, but according to [Net::Daemon::Log](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aDaemon%3a%3aLog) docs it should work.

Comment: When I start the proxy-server with the config-file it works. Does this work, because IO::File and IO::Socket from Net::Daemon inherit from IO::Handle?

Comment: @sid_com - both `IO::Handle` and `IO::File` are included in core package called `IO`. They are object interface for perl I/O subsystem. If you use IO::Handle/IO::File in any script, `open` will also return objects of this class.