# IO - documentation - question

Tags: perl, documentation, io, filehandle

> both IO::Handle and IO::File are included in core package called IO. They are object interface for perl I/O subsystem. If you use IO::Handle/IO::File in any script, open will also return objects of this class.

(bvr's comment from [DBI::ProxyServer: Problem with writing a log-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219859/dbiproxyserver-problem-with-writing-a-log-file))

Is there a good place in the documentation where I can read about this?

Comment: http://p3rl.org/IO::Handle http://p3rl.org/IO::File

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to start with [IO::Handle](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Handle.html), then look at pages referenced in SEE ALSO section.